# Comment s'appellent les habitants du Moyen-Orient ?

Tags: terminologie

Peut-on dire les *« moyen-orientaux »* ?

Le terme que je recherche dois rassembler aussi bien les Égyptiens que les Turcs et les Iraniens donc le mot *« Arabes »* ne convient pas.

Comment: Je pense que le mieux est "habitants du Moyen-Orient". Car la définition de "moyen-orientaux" n'a pas l'air de concerner les habitants, mais est plutot un [adjectif](http://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/moyen-oriental_moyen-orientale_moyen-orientaux/53045)...

Comment: « Habitants du Moyen-Orient » me semble être la meilleure formulation, comme expliqué par user3817755. Par ailleurs, la réponse de Toto semble être erronnée.
Ainsi, dans le lien qu'il fournit (!), une des définitions est : « Habitants du Levant qui ne sont ni Turcs ni Arabes (Lar. Lang. fr.) ».

Comment: @Random, si _orientaux_ peut etre utilisé comme un nom, pourquoi _moyen-orientaux_ ne peut pas l'être ?

Comment: @Arone -- Pas terrible : moyens s'entend médiocres lorsque l'on parle de personnes. En arrière pensée : "Ah ce ne sont pas des orientaux supérieurs ?"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Il existe un terme peu précis dans ton cas : "les orientaux" (en opposition aux "occidentaux"). Or, ce terme englobe les habitants du proche orient à l’extrême orient. Tu peux cependant l'utiliser si le contexte indique clairement et précisément qu'il s'agit du moyen orient.

Le terme "moyen-oriental" existe mais il s'applique à tout ce qui est relatif au moyen orient, pas forcément aux habitants de la région.

Quant au terme "arabe", il est plus ethnique et culturel que géographique.

Par conséquent, "habitants du Moyen-Orient" semble être la formulation la plus précise.

Answer (score 3):

Je pense que *« [Levantin](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/levantin) »* pourrait convenir.

Comment: Levantin ne convient pas car ce terme désigne d'après le lien que tu donnes,  les "Habitants du Levant qui ne sont ni Turcs ni Arabes". Le terme que je recherche doit aussi permettre de parler des Turcs et des Arabes.

Comment: @Arone Le même lien donne "Matelots des côtes de la Turquie et de l'Asie Mineure" ; le Robert:  "**Qui est originaire des côtes de la Méditerranée orientale** : Les peuples levantins...". C'est une limitation ancienne : "De nos jours en Turquie, le terme « Levantin »  désigne uniquement les ressortissants turcs d'origine occidentale - Wikipédia) - La côte levantine s'entend du Bosphore au delta du Nil, même si l'on pense à l'extrême Est de la Méditerranée définit par la ligne Nord-Sud Syrie-Palestine.

Answer (score 3):

Le moyen orient est une conception britannique de la zone Égypte-Iran, Péninsule arabique-Turquie.

En France on utilise Proche-Orient, qui au départ recouvrait les pays levantins, avec des nuances selon les époques.

Pour ne pas prêter à confusion on peut dire Proche et Moyen-Orient, mais si l'on parle de *proches-orientaux*, on se fera comprendre : tous les habitants du moyen-orient actuel seront pris en compte.

Mais il y a une multitude d’ethnies, de religions, de langues, de cultures, d'histoires, de civilisations pour ne pas enrober dans un seul adjectif de telles richesses civilisatrices.

Pour ma part j'emploie ***les peuples du Proche-Orient*** ou ***les peuples du Moyen-Orient*** lorsque je ne veux pas parler d'un de ces peuples en particulier.

Mais cela peut être contesté, ce n'est qu'un moyen pour ne pas utiliser *les moyens-orientaux* qui sonne mal (lorsque que moyen est accolé à une personne, on 'traduit' souvent par *médiocre*), car il n'y a pas *d'orientaux supérieurs* ni *d'orientaux inférieurs*.

Answer (score 0):

Tu peux dire

> Les gens moyen-orientaux

L'adjectif veut dire "relatif au Moyen-Orient".